# Do we have any forum on Stack Exchange for queries on Shakespearean English queries?

Tags: discussion, resource-request

I am looking forward to ask interpretation on poetry and Shakespeare's drama play's  text. Is there any forum to discuss the same. Is ELL Stack Exchange relevant for such questions?

Answer (score 4):

This isn’t really the best site for that sort of question.   Instead, I suggest you try [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com).  Make sure to look through their Help Center before posting, so you know what sorts of questions are on-topic or off-topic there.